# pip install tabulate UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install the python package `tabulate` by running `pip3 install tabulate` on Archlinux but i got the following error:

```
Downloading/unpacking tabulate
Downloading tabulate-0.6.tar.gz
Running setup.py egg_info for package tabulate
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
File "/tmp/pip_build_user/tabulate/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
LONG_DESCRIPTION = open("README.rst").read().replace("`_", "`")
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 8035: ordinal 
not in range(128)
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

File "/tmp/pip_build_user/tabulate/setup.py", line 8, in <module>

LONG_DESCRIPTION = open("README.rst").read().replace("`_", "`")


File "/usr/lib/python3.3/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode

return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 8035: ordinal not in range(128)

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_user/tabulate
`Storing complete log in /home/user/.pip/pip.log
```

I'm running:

- python -V -> Python 3.3.2
- pip3 -V -> pip 1.4.1 from /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages (python 3.3)

I have successfully installed other packages by pip and I don't know why this occurs suddenly. Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

***Solution***
It *looked like* a locale issue on my OS. Had to overwrite the global LANG environment variable to LANG="en_US.UTF-8".

Comment: You could post your solution as an answer and then accept it. Then people will know the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution** It looked like a locale issue on my OS. Had to overwrite the global LANG environment variable to LANG="en_US.UTF-8".

Comment: Which was the value before?

Comment: @andres.riancho it was "de_DE.UTF-8"

Comment: Thanks, this will help me debug some similar issues I'm having.