# UnicodeDecodeError thrown by pip

Tags: python, pip

I see that decoding errors are common with `pip` but I can't apply any solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/upgrading-all-packages-with-pip) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180521/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-3-6-invalid-dat) to my problem.

I have a Raspberry Pi (4.4.11-v7+). When I try to upgrade a package with `pip install <module> --upgrade` I get this error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 348: invalid start byte
```

with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==8.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip.compat import console_to_str, expanduser, stdlib_pkgs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/compat/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import ipaddress
```

I am not sure on how to intervene on line 24 to resolve the encoding issue though.

Comment: What package were you trying to upgrade? Usually including the full traceback is a good idea.

Comment: I get the same error with every package I try to install

Comment: That's good info, but could you still provide the full traceback?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440958/cant-run-pip-unicodedecodeerror? IIC a "poisonous" module (some funny encoding) may cause the blow up as pip is using pkg_resources.

Comment: This is the *full* traceback? There is nothing after `from pip._vendor import ipaddress` other then the `UnicodeDecodeError`?

Comment: @SiHa Yes it is the full traceback