# pip UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, pip

I run `pip`, and I always get the following error, no matter what flags I pass to `pip`:

```
$ pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
    [...irrelevant details omitted...]
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/codecs.py", line 314, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 203: invalid start byte
```

What's going on?  How do I fix this?

I have pip version 8.0.2 installed.  Changing or clearing the `LANG` and `LC_ALL` environment variables doesn't help.  I must have read a dozen other questions here but I'm struggling to find anything that provides a clear indication of what the problem is or how to fix it.

Answer (score 11):

### What's going on

`pip` is buggy.  It can crashes if any installed Python system library has a non-ASCII character in the library description.

The relevant part of the error message is this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte ...
```

The specific byte value isn't important.  The crash is triggered by a certain kind of non-ASCII character in a `.egg-info` file in the system directory where Python packages are stored (e.g., `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`).  `pip` tries to parse all of those files, and when it encounters certain non-ASCII characters, it falls over and dies.

### How to fix the problem

There are two options:

1. **The right fix:** Update `pip` to the latest version.  This fixes the bug.
2. **The kludge:** Remove the offending Python library package that triggers `pip` to crash.  That requires you to figure out which Python library package is responsible; unfortunately, `pip` doesn't give you much help figuring that out, so you're going to have to do some sleuthing to figure that out -- see the next section.

Obviously, the former option is preferable... but if for some reason you cannot upgrade `pip`, I'll describe how to follow the second approach.

### How to find the Python library that's responsible for this

Here's how you can check your Python system packages and narrow down which one might be responsible for `pip`'s crashes.  We're going to look for any `*.egg-info` file in the Python `site-packages/` directory that has a non-ASCII character.  Try this:

```
cd /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
LANG=ascii grep -P  '[[:^ascii:]]' *.egg-info 2>/dev/null
```

(This requires GNU grep.)  Look through the matches it finds.  Check each file to see if it contains a non-ASCII character that matches the error message.

In my case, the error message mentioned `can't decode byte 0xf6`, so we're going to look for the file that contains a `0xf6` byte.  We can inspect each matching file using a hex dump utility; I like to use `hexdump -C`.

To find the match, you might need to check other locations for Python packages, e.g., `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages`, `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, and so on.

Once you find the Python package that is causing the problems, you can try removing that library (if it is not an essential package).

### Other possible explanations and troubleshooting steps

On older systems, this error could also be triggered if your current path or your username contains any non-ASCII characters.

Some people reported that they had success by clearing the `LC_ALL` and `LANG` environment variables, or by setting them to different settings, such as `export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`.  This didn't help for me, though.

### Other reading

References that I found helpful:

- [Can't run pip: UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34440958/781723)
- [pip install UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25036897/781723)

Comment: I have the same error with latest pip version (20.0.1) does it mean there is nothing i can do but digging into libraries?

Comment: @ADOConnection, I don't know.  Why don't you start by following the directions for the "kludge" to identify which library might be the cause, check if removing it causes the problem to go away, find out as much information as you can to narrow it down, and if that seems to be the cause, file a bug report with the pip maintainers?

Comment: @dw sure, asking just to make sure nothing changed since 2017